Tv series about a guy who went back to the past
I happened to see a couple of episodes of this TV series, which looks very similar to Hercules/Xena. I have watched it in Italy, so it was in Italian, I would say between 2000-2005.
This guy was back in the past (I think because of an electromagnetic portal in the forest), in possession of a walkman and some technology from the future.
He was taken prisoner from some people that become aware of his knowledge and asked to create some explosive (I remember him creating some bombs with gunpowder or something like that)
I don't remember much else. Does anyone know what I am talking about?

Hi! Do you remember the year? Was it American? Where\when did you see it?

Hi! I have watched in Italy, so it was in italian, I would say between 2000/2005. Thanks!

@MeV How the lead actor looked like and was he traveling alone or with a group?

@madmada I have never seen him traveling, he was alone in the episode I have seen, he was showing the walkman to a girl of the past he could trust

Could this be Spellbinder ( 1995– )?
Walkman scene:https://youtu.be/PoGFXr7bFc0?t=218
and gunpowder episode:http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0933635/

@pori YESSSSSSSSSSSSS!!!!! You are a genious!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much! I cannot believe it I have finally found it!!!!!!! :))))))))

I watched Spellbinder as a kid, but I would never guess that this question is about it :-) Well done @pori!

Spellbinder

A group of teenagers go on a school camp in the Blue Mountains in Australia. While at the camp, Paul Reynolds accidentally goes into a parallel universe. This other world is inhabited by a more hierarchic and technologically different society, ruled by a group of people known as Spellbinders. Paul meets a girl there named Riana, and they become friends.
Episode 3: After narrowly escaping the Spellbinder's flying ship,
  Paul tries to convince Riana that he's not dangerous to be around, and
  wins her over by showing her his cassette player.
Episode 7:With a promise to be set free if he reveals the secret
  to making gunpowder, Paul keeps Gryvon busy preparing a diversionary
  concoction while he creates the real thing to provide a proper
  demonstration for Ashka. Not trusting Paul, Ashka has Gryvon secretly
  follow Paul's instructions on his own to make another batch of
  gunpowder to check the accuracy of Paul's recipe. Escaping from Ashka
  in the castle cells, Riana disguises herself as a castle worker to
  hide in plain site. After witnessing Paul helping Ashka and Gryvon
  make gunpowder, Riana alerts Correon to Ashka's deception. The two
  groups all converge on the ruins of a Spellbinder castle that was
  destroyed in The Darkness time to witness the testing of Paul's
  gunpowder. Despite the successful test, Ashka refuses to release Paul.


I think you're after the episode The Time Machine of The New Adventures of Robin Hood, a show that was stylistically very similar to Hercules and Xena.

Elvis, a descendant of Barkley's, appears from the future in a time
  machine, interrupting a battle between Robin's band and Lord Rudolph's
  band of marauders. The marauders steal the time machine, but it will
  explode with unimaginable destructive power if it is not returned to
  the time it came from within 24 hours. Rowena befriends Elvis, and
  they fly through the forest on magical skateboards to escape the
  marauders. Robin races to return Elvis to his own time before
  disaster.

You can see the whole episode on YT:



The time traveller in a portal-like time machine can be seen on 7:50. Starting from 28:00 you can see the explosives in use.

In fact I missed the part where you explain that it was several episodes about the time traveler, not only one, so I guess it's not a correct answer. However I'll leave it for now, just in case.

Ha ha! Thank you so much for your answer!! This episode is very similar but not the one I am talking about. But this is funny cause everything I have described is happening in this episode too! :-D Thanks again for your message

@MeV No problem, in that case I won't delete the answer, maybe someone else will benefit from it.
